# Error connecting SMTP Port 25 through Linux/Ubuntu EC2

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, smtp, email-server

I have setup an EC2 Linux instance. and trying to setup a mailserver on it, But as i am trying to send a test mail via SMTP port:25 , it gives me Timeout error.

I have opened the SMTP port on security group, but still I am getting the same error.

Do we have any workaround/ solution to fix this particular issue.

Thanks In Advance

Comment: Try a remote network scan to check whether the port is reachable or not:  
`nmap ec2linuxinstance -p 25`

Comment: its up, I got these results: Host is up (0.0010s latency).
PORT   STATE    SERVICE
25/tcp filtered smtp

Comment: To be precise in error : *** Error connecting to smtp.mailgun.org:25:
***     IO::Socket::INET: connect: timeout

Comment: If you are trying to connect from your home internet, that might not work. Some ISPs block port 25 to reduce spam.

Comment: @jordanm, not in this case as I made the OP perform a network scan and it suceeded:
`Host is up (0.0010s latency). PORT STATE SERVICE 25/tcp filtered smtp`

Comment: @MikeL'Angelo "filtered" means a firewall is blocking the port. https://nmap.org/book/man.html

Comment: @jordanm of course it is evidence of a firewall. This is why I advised the OP to "double check your security group configuration because it is not allowing your host to reach SMTP port". But also, I noticed a long wait  for the connection to port 25 to be established. Outgoing port 25 TCP block by is not frequent unless in public hotspots or in companies but yes, you're right, the Filtered reposnse could also mean that. \

Answer (score 0):

I can succesfully

```
~$ telnet smtp.mailgun.org 25
Trying 34.215.189.196...
Connected to smtp.mailgun.org.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 ak47 ESMTP ready
helo test.me
250 ak47
mail from:myself@test.me
250 2.0.0 OK
RCPT TO: <whatever>@gmail.com
550 5.7.1 Relaying denied
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

You should provide the code you are using to connect to the SMTP service.

You probably need to

- double check your security group configuration because it is not allowing your host to reach SMTP port, whereas mine can.

and/or

- increase timeout options in your code.